# Unable to get result from a remote server using asp.net web application hosted on iss

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis

I want to run some command on a remote server commandline and get the result back on my local server. For this I am using psexec.exe in my C# code.
When I do this using my console application it's working fine and I can see the result of the command run in commandline of remote server in my log file.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
string results;
sInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
sInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
sInfo.Arguments = "/C \"psexec.exe \\\\" + servername + " -u " + user + " -p " + pasword + " " + command1 + "\"";
p.StartInfo = sInfo;
p.Start();
results = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

But when I implement the same logic for a web application hosted on a iis server it doesn't work. I have already tried the below things:

1) implementing the above logic in my web application which should run on the occurance of an event like click of a button. It doesn't work.

2) I have tried creating a .bat file having content same as sinfo.argument with actual server name psword and other details. When I run this bat file manually it runs fine and shows the result in console. But when I trigger that bat file with my web application it doesnt't work.

3) I have given the location of my console application exe in bat file and then when I run the .bat file it again gives perfect result. But when I trigger the .bat file with web application I fails again.

4) I have tried triggering my consoleapplication.exe directly using my web application and it doesn't work.

So I suspect there is some problem in getting the result from remote server using web application hosted on iis. I think the code is not exiting with error code 0 when run using web application. But same works fine with a console application.

Comment: What user does the applicationpool run as? What user are you running the console application as? Is the only specified user set in the -u switch? Have you tried the `Process.WaitForExit()` (not ideal for a web application)?

Comment: the user set in the -u switch is the user id of the remote server. i am running both the console and web application as an administrator of my local server.

Comment: yes i have tried using Process.WaitForExit() also. but doesn't work.

Comment: could it be something related to impersonation on IIS